# How to update a specific cell with a numeric value?

Tags: r

I am reading in a CSV file.  When I first check if there are any NA's there are none.  I then clean my data and convert my Income variable from num to factor by using this code to discretize income by equal-width bins:

```
min_income <- min(bd$income)
max_income <- max(bd$income)
bins = 3 
width=(max_income - min_income)/bins;
bd$income = cut(bd$income, breaks=seq(min_income, max_income, width))
```

When I complete cleaning/updating my data and check again for NA's I receive one.  It is specific to row 65 for my income column.  If I want to update the actual value in it, using the below code I receive an error.

```
> bd[65,5] = 5014.21
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Is there a way to update this without having to change the type of variable?  Why would it change the value to an NA (especially for only one value)?  I have not come across this issue previously.  I could just remove the row, but since I have the value I figured I should just use it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the NA value is the lowest value because `cut()` does not include the lower boundary by default. You can change that by setting `include_lowest = TRUE`. See example below.

```
bd = data.frame(income = sample(seq(100,500, 10), 10))

min_income <- min(bd$income)
max_income <- max(bd$income)
bins = 3 
width=(max_income - min_income)/bins;
bd$income2 = cut(bd$income, breaks=seq(min_income, max_income, width))
bd$income3 = cut(bd$income, breaks=seq(min_income, max_income, width),
                 include.lowest = TRUE)
```

```
bd
   income   income2   income3
1     340 (247,373] (247,373]
2     360 (247,373] (247,373]
3     250 (247,373] (247,373]
4     120      <NA> [120,247]
5     290 (247,373] (247,373]
6     210 (120,247] [120,247]
7     440 (373,500] (373,500]
8     500 (373,500] (373,500]
9     450 (373,500] (373,500]
10    380 (373,500] (373,500]
```

So there should be no need to have an NA value in need of changing in the first place. However, for the sake of completeness: You change `bd$income` into a factor and hence can only assign a value corresponding to a factor level. For instance like this:

```
bd$income2[is.na(bd$income2)] = levels(bd$income2)[1]
bd
   income   income2   income3
1     340 (247,373] (247,373]
2     360 (247,373] (247,373]
3     250 (247,373] (247,373]
4     120 (120,247] [120,247]
5     290 (247,373] (247,373]
6     210 (120,247] [120,247]
7     440 (373,500] (373,500]
8     500 (373,500] (373,500]
9     450 (373,500] (373,500]
10    380 (373,500] (373,500]
```